# How can I have CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE being propagated to sublibraries included via add_subdirectory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

My build consists of several sub-libraries being first build and then linked together.

In the main cmakelists.txt they're added with

```
add_subdirectory (src/submodules/CanTp/CanTp CanTp)
```

and a linker dependency is added with

```
target_link_libraries(my_app_name PRIVATE CanTp/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/CanTp
```

The cmakelists.txt for CanTp is

```
add_library (CanTp CanTp.cpp)

target_include_directories (CanTp PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

The issue is that CanTp is always built with build type Debug regardless of CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE. CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE does have an effect on the build type for the sources files in the top cmakelists.txt so I know it's set correctly.

How can I have CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE being propagated to sublibraries included via add_subdirectory?

Comment: "The issue is that CanTp is always built with build type Debug" - How do you determine that? Have you checked its compile flags, and found them being corresponding to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` and not to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`? Variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` like many other CMake variables are propagated to subdirectories. Also, why do you link with `CanTp/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/CanTp`? If you want to link with the library corresponded to **target** `CanTp`, then use given target for link with: `target_link_libraries(my_app_name PRIVATE CanTp)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I determine that CanTp is always build as debug because Visual Studio (the compiler used in this case) puts the output in folders named after build type ("Debug") in this case. That's also why I link with  CanTp/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/CanTp. When I try to link with the given target, as you suggest, the linker doesn't find the library file because Visual studio has placed it in a folder "CanTp\Debug"

Comment: Oh, so it is Visual Studio... This generator is **multiconfiguration**: the project is configured for several configurations **at once**. The variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` means nothing for Visual Studio. "When I try to link with the given target, as you suggest, the linker doesn't find the library file because Visual studio has placed it in a folder "CanTp\Debug"" - CMake should properly translate the target into the library path. Probably, something wrong with your code. Please, add your code into the question post (in form of [mcve]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @Tsyvarev the Visual Studio CMake generator is a multiconfiguration generator which means it provides all configurations at once. `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` only has an effect for single configuration generators like `Unix Makefiles`.

To support both types of generators you shouldn't read `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` unless you've got a good reason to do so and have checked, if the current configuration uses a single configuration generator.

The preferred way of specifying configuration dependent properties is to use [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7)). They cannot be used everywhere and sometimes properties allow for generator expressions only since a specific CMake version.

`target_link_libraries` allows for the use of generator expressions since Version `3.0` though, so in this case there shouldn't be an issue with using them.

```
target_link_libraries(my_app_name PRIVATE CanTp/$<CONFIG>/CanTp)
```

This works for both single configuration generators and multi configuration generators. You should specify the configuration via command line parameter though.

**Windows/Visual Studio**

```
mkdir build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -S src -B build
cmake --build build --config Debug
```

**Unix/Make**

```
mkdir build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -S src -B build
cmake --build build
```